# array don't view in blade template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

```
$udata = DB::table('student_info')
    ->join('student_academy', 'student_info.student_id', '=', 'student_academy.student_id')
    ->where('student_info.student_id',  $id)
    ->where('student_academy.student_id', $id)
    ->get();
```

dd($udata); ---> Here is ok. and i tried 3 way:

1. return view('pages.student.editStudent', compact('udata'));
2. return view('pages.student.editStudent', ['udata'=> $udata]);
3. return view('pages.student.editStudent')->with('udata', $udata );

   But every time Display this error

   (2/2) ErrorException
   Property [s_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

where is my mistake ??

Comment: `get` returns a collection. Collections do not have a property named `s_name`. The 'items' in the collection may have that property though.

Comment: check ur blade file. or paste error trace screenshot

Comment: post here the output of `dd($udata)`.

Comment: error is --->  ErrorException Property [s_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2):

try this way..

```
 @foreach($udata as $data)
    {{$data->s_name}}
    @endforeach

    or

{{$udata[0]->s_name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{udata[0]['s_name']}}` instead